# COMPLETELY removing files from Github history including API history

Tags: github, github-api

I've learned it is possible to get SHA's for old blobs by using

`curl https://api.github.com/repos/[ user ]/[ repo ]/events`

The SHAs can be used to recover specific commits and files purged from the git history and pushed to origin can still be found. Every single file from all commits can be recovered.

Tools like BFG don't seem to remove these references. Other than completely deleting the repo and re-committing it, how can all events or all SHAs found in event references be removed? Otherwise, a single commit of sensative information dooms the entire repo short of the drastic aforementioned measures.

Comment: I suspect your only option will be to contact GitHub support and ask them to do this for you. (Though any sensitive information like API keys or database credentials that you've accidentally committed should always be invalidated and regenerated.)

Comment: Hi Chris, I understand that. However, private assets may be committed as well. They can be removed a moment later yet they remain in the history of event in GitHub with no way (that I know) to invalidate the file reference.

Comment: I've contact GitHub on this matter as well